# What is the fastest way to add email / markdown citation to some block of text?

Tags: linux, email, markdown, citations

I often have some text block on a website a PDF file, etc. that I want to add email / markdown style citation to.

So for example I want to turn this:

```
This is a quote that possible is very long and / or spans multiple lines.

Blablabla […]

And another line.
```

Into this:

```
> This is a quote that possible is very long and / or spans multiple lines.
> 
> Blablabla […]
> 
> And another line.
```

What is a faster way to do this than manually adding `>` in front of every line?

Comment: It probably depends on the specific implementation - on here you would just select your text & hit ctrl/q. Having said that, web apps are off-topic on this stack - voting to migrate [though you will have to add more detail to avoid the migration simply being rejected]

Comment: That Ctrl-Q function is exactly what I need, but I would like to have it as a standalone tool. Maybe I should ask on softwarerecs.se.

Comment: This could probably be achieved in [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). You select the text, then press a hotkey which copies the text to clipboard, does a search for line ending and inserts the `>` after each, puts it back in the clipboard and pasted it back into your application. Might have a go later. It would mean another small program constantly running on your computer, but you can set up all sorts of hot keys to insert bits of text or do random things.

Comment: On which platform? On anything vaguely Unix-y, `sed 's/^/> /'`; but of course, ultimately, [Emacs.](https://xkcd.com/378/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small shell script to solve the problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
CLIPBOARD=`xclip -selection clipboard -o`
MODDED_CLIPBOARD=`echo "$CLIPBOARD" | sed 's/^/> /'`
echo "$MODDED_CLIPBOARD" | xclip -selection clipboard -i
```

It reads the clipboard, adds `>` in front of every line and puts the result back into the clipboard.

Of course with files it's even easier:

```
sed 's/^/> /' filename
```